Flutter build failed error when trying to run my application
enter image description hereFlutter error
I was building an app through flutter and when i update my android studio and java version then this error of mergeDexDebug error occurred, i have tried to update my gradle version and also added multidexed property but it failed.
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: D:\Sachin K\Desktop\moneymatee\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> Error while dexing: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "" is null

I have tried the following solutions, but the error persists:
Updated the gradle-wrapper.properties to the latest compatible Gradle version.
Updated the Android Gradle Plugin in android/build.gradle.
Enabled multidex by adding the following to android/app/build.gradle:
Here’s a well-structured question for StackOverflow:
Title:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug' in Flutter after updating Android Studio and Java
Description:
I was building a Flutter app, and everything was working fine until I updated my Android Studio and Java versions. After the updates, I started encountering the following error when running my app:
plaintext
Copy code
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, ...}.
> Error while dexing.
I have tried the following solutions, but the error persists:

Updated the gradle-wrapper.properties to the latest compatible Gradle version.
Updated the Android Gradle Plugin in android/build.gradle.
Enabled multidex by adding the following to android/app/build.gradle:
gradle
Copy code
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
Ensured my minSdkVersion is set to 21 in android/app/build.gradle:
gradle
Copy code
android {
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 21
...
}
}
Cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times:
bash
Copy code
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk
Verified dependencies to ensure no version conflicts by running flutter pub deps.
Environment:
Flutter version:3.19
Android Studio version: ladybug(2024)
Java version: 21
Gradle version: 8.5

Have you attempted to repair your pub cache? flutter pub cache repair
